# Is it a good idea for a 21 year old engineer (or similar) with some lump sum of money and good income to invest?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies

I am fresh out of university and landed a good graduate job with a decent acceptance bonus. I would like to start investing and not lose any time in doing so, however, it can be intimidating to not only risk all the money being invested at a young age but also to sign paperwork without any legal endurance or knowledge.

Would it be a good idea to start opening an investment account in places like JP Morgan or BlackRock and start growing individual wealth?

Comment: Be aware than there can be a big difference in the ease of getting money out between a brokerage (e.g. Fidelity, Vanguard) and a mutual fund held directly with the manager (e.g. BlackRock, Primecap).  Waiting for a paper check to come in the mail really delays getting your money.

Comment: While this was flagged as a duplicate, if you're left with any other questions after reading through those answers don't hesitate to create a new question to ask, a lot of times the wording is just different enough that you don't find similar relevant questions, so no shame in having a question closed.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "invest".  Actively trading individual stocks, or putting money in index funds?  IMHO the first is a bad idea, unless you are doing it for enjoyment (and will be ok with potentially losing most of your money).  Putting spare money in index funds or similar, where you can just forget them, makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the longer the money keep invested the lower is the risk.

Another point to consider, if you put the money on a bank account the average gain is lower ... Put keep some money for quick unexpected investments, if you are forced to sell stock it can be "bad timing" and rather quick buys and sells have a relativ high amount of fees included.

As a beginner i would suggest, going for 1 or more etf investment plan - they offer you diversification a bit protection against bad timing and you can start with little money.